# mySQLi Debugging Issues

Tags: php, mysqli

I actually have this PHP code, which i use to obtain my database info..

```
function searchUserEmail($username, $raw_email){
    //Prepare Statements
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
    //Sanitize Input
    $user = $this->conn->real_escape_string($username);
    $email = $this->conn->real_escape_string($raw_email);

    if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        }
    }

    if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query2)){
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
                $stmt->close();
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've tried this alot of times, ran it through a statement checker, still it doesn't work. Is there anything i'm missing???

Somehow it always returns a false (Even though its suppose to return true)

Comment: What exactly is the issue? When or where is it occuring?

Comment: You have to debug your code mister.

Comment: output of $this->conn->error?

Answer (score -1):

mysql_select_db($dataname,$conn);

Comment: Considering the OP is using $this->conn, we can guess that it's part of the class function, though it's not shown. And since they're using prepare with bind_param, they're using mysqli, not mysql_* functions.

Comment: Its mySQLi firstly...And i've debugged my code (Or at least tried to with whatever limited knowledge i have), but it doesn't seem to run any errors, just give me the value zero rows returned...(Although that's impossible), or may i should rephrase my question to be is there anyway to echo the mySQLi prepared statement? @Corrupt, the issue is when i try to run it e.g. <?php if(searchUserEmail('admin','test123@test.com') == True){ echo 'We found it';} ?> it returns the false of searchUserEmail even though it should be true...(ie, echo not displayed).

Comment: In case you're wondering, my DB has one entry and its 

ID   Username   Email
1     admin     test123@test.com